# Is there foursquare developer roadmap?

Tags: api, foursquare

I just wanted to know if there is a developer roadmap for foursquare. We're developing an application using foursquare api and we dont want to break its functionality when there's changes within foursquare api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that future Foursquare API changes won't break your application, be sure to supply a [version parameter](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning) with all your API requests. This parameter is a date you give that basically says "use the version of the API that was running on this date." Now if the API does indeed change, your application will get results from the previous version of the API, and you have adequate time to transition to the newer version.

In general, you can stay most up-to-date by following the Foursquare [Engineering Blog](http://engineering.foursquare.com/) and [@foursquareAPI](https://twitter.com/foursquareAPI). There's also a [changelog](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/changelog) on the developer site.

Comment: Hey man thanks! good to know about what the version parameter does.